# Linear algebra, minimal polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, minimal-polynomials

Prove or disprove:

If matrix $A$ is invertible, then the constant term of its minimal polynomial 
is not equal to $0$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Minimal polynomial for an invertible matrix and its determinant](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1291427/minimal-polynomial-for-an-invertible-matrix-and-its-determinant)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A matrix is invertible if and only if its determinant is nonzero. Also if we work over an algebraically closed field, since determinants are invariant under change of basis, we can compute them in the canonical basis to see that the determinant is just the product of the eigenvalues. Finally, according to [Vieta's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), the constant term of the characteristic polynomial is the product of the eigenvalues. The minimal polynomial is also just a product of powers of the irreducible linear factors of the characteristic polynomial, so its constant term is just the product of powers of the eigenvalues.

Comment: I'm talking about the minimal polynomial.

Comment: @RonLibman oh, I see. Oops

Comment: @RonLibman ok I have edited to address minimal polynomial

Answer (score 1):

If $p(x)=a_0x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+...+a_{n-1}x+a_n$, then $p(0)=a_n$.

Hence: $A$ is invertible $ \iff$ $0$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$ $ \iff p(0) \ne 0 \iff a_n \ne 0$

Answer (score 0):

For a more direct proof : suppose that $A$ is invertible and its minimal polynomial $p$ has constant term $0$. Then $p=X\cdot q$ for some polynomial $q$ with degree less than $p$. Moreover $0=p(A)=A\cdot q(A)$, and since $A$ is invertible, $q(A)=0$. This contradicts the fact that $p$ is the minimal polynomial of $A$.